# In Wordpress, why would one parent menu display submenu items and not another?

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

What in the world would cause sub menu items to only display properly when under only ONE parent menu item?

http://www.volusiarootcanals.com/wordpress/insurance-fees/

WHAT WE DO has 4 sub menu items that fly out to the right. But, when I go to Appearances > Menus, and move the sub items to any other parent menu item, they won't display on the front end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your js code for the menu?

Comment: Please bear with me, I'm not sure. Developer took the 2014 theme and I'm not sure why this wouldn't work out of the box. Do you think there is an exclude somewhere?  Or, an include to only allow subs for the one parent? Where should I look for js?  header template?